# Replacing JavaServer Faces Error Pages

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets

Is it possible to replace the standard error pages from [JavaServer Faces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) such as

`500 Internal Server Error`

?

These include information such as the stack trace, etc. But for the users, when the page is in Production Mode, I want to show a friendlier page saying that the request did not succeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The development stack trace is probably coming from your JSF implementation. The code for disabling it will be specific to the impementation. For [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/) in Servlets, use this init parameter in your `web.xml`:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

If you're using the Sun implementation ([Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/)), there may be some `com.sun.faces...` keyed parameter.

You may also want to check the value of [Facelets init parameter](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#config-webapp-init) `facelets.DEVELOPMENT` (make sure you haven't set it to `true`).

To specify an error page, you can use the usual container mechanisms. For Servlets, this would be by [specifying a error pages in](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html#bnaet) `web.xml`, keyed to either exception types or error codes. To catch all throwables...

```
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/errorPage.faces</location>
  </error-page>
```

You might find additional vendor-specific support for error handling in the JSF implementations - you'd have to check their documentation.

Comment: Thanks, great answer! One follow up question though, would it be possible to use the error message on the catching page?(errorPage.faces)

Comment: Oh and by the way, where do i find a list of all the com.sun.faces... keyed parameters? I am not using Myfaces, i am using JSF 1.2 with Facelets.

Comment: To get the error message, try the expression `#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}`. To get the exception, use `javax.servlet.error.exception` - see the Servlet spec for a full list error values set to the request map (if you want the error code, etc). You can Mojarra context params in the Glassfish FAQ: http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=JavaServerFacesRI#section-JavaServerFacesRI-WhatContextParametersAreAvailableAndWhatDoTheyDo

Comment: Having the following:   <error-page>
 <error-code>500</error-code>
 <location>/error.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
doesn't seem to work, the page is just blank, when i add /error.jsf to my URL it works but not when i get an error, any ideas on that?

Comment: If you redirect to an error page by error code, I don't think the exception is set (so any exceptions/messages will be null). Probably because an exception is not the only way to trigger an error code. Try redirecting based on the exception type. Otherwise, all I can say is that it works on my machine...

Comment: I see, well I changed the XML-file so that it looks like this now:     <error-page>
 <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
 <location>/nullerror.xhtml</location>
    </error-page> however that displays the xhtml and not the correct jsf-encoded stuff. and when i change it to nullerror.jsf it's just blank, but when i navigate to it, it displays the content. Really weird, you getting any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: It may be that the error state your app enters prevents the JSF lifecycle from being able to function. If you get really stuck, you can always switch to a non-JSF JSP to use for the error page. You may be able to use a servlet filter to do some error handling/redirection too if necessary.